# Java- Returning different classes based on generic type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, constructor

I would like to create a class that will take in different types. It should handle some basic operations like .equals() for all given types, but I'd like to create specific implementations for Strings and Booleans for example.

I'd like to use the same constructor but control what happens based on the type.

```
public class TestObject<T>{
     private T value;

     public TestObject{

     }

     public setValue(T value){
         this.value=value;
     }

     public return Type??? getSpecificType(){
        if (value instanceof Boolean){
        return new TestObjectBoolean(this);
        }
        if (value  instanceof String){
        return new TestObjectString(this);
        }
     }

}
```

The desired usage below:

```
TestObject<String> test = new TestObject<String>();
test.setValue("Test");
boolean result = test.getSpecificType().stringSpecificMethod()

TestObject<Integer> test2 = new TestObject<Boolean>();
test.setValue(true);
boolean result2= test2.getSpecificType().booleanSpecificMethod();
```

I would like the below example to fail to compile:

```
TestObject<String> test3 = new TestObject<String>();
test.setValue("Test");
boolean result3= test3.getSpecificType().booleanSpecificMethod();
//should not compile because test2 should return a boolean specific class 
//with the boolean specific methods
```

It may seem silly but I would like to avoid calling differently named constructors for different types like this:

```
TestObjectString test4 = new TestObjectString();
test.setValue("Test");
boolean result4= test4.stringSpecificMethod();
```

I am lost on how to implement this. Any advice or help on searching additional information on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't, simply put. Generic types are erased (i.e. unknown) at runtime.

Comment: Make that method return `Something<T>`.

Comment: `TestObjectBoolean` and `TestObjectString` inherit from the same class and you return that class.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, but I'd like to limit their methods so that I cannot call a string specific method when it returns an instance of TestObjectBoolean

Comment: This is one of the things subclasses are for:  to provide specific behavior that a general superclass does not and cannot specify.  Trying to provide String-specific and booleans-specific methods on a single class is bad design.

Comment: @VGR I would like to return separate classes, but I also would like to read the type passed and if it matches a certain type, return the specific classes. Your comment does not address the issue. Am I simply out of luck? There is no other way to do this besides calling individual constructors for the specific classes?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking for, but I think you want to make the constructor private, and add public factory methods:

```
public class TestObject<T> {

    private T value;

    private final Supplier<? extends TestObject<T>> typeSpecificConstructor;

    private TestObject(T initialValue,
                       Supplier<? extends TestObject<T>> constructor) {
        this.value = initialValue;
        this.typeSpecificConstructor = constructor;
    }

    protected TestObject(Supplier<? extends TestObject<T>> constructor) {
        this.typeSpecificConstructor = constructor;
    }

    public boolean test(T valueToTest) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Must be implemented by subclasses");
    }

    public static TestObject<Boolean> newInstance(boolean initialValue) {
        return new TestObject<>(initialValue, TestObjectBoolean::new);
    }

    public static TestObject<String> newInstance(String initialValue) {
        return new TestObject<>(initialValue, TestObjectString::new);
    }

    public TestObject<T> getSpecificType() {
        return typeSpecificConstructor.get();
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

But methods particular to a subtype still won’t be accessible.  There is simply no way for a variable whose type is a general superclass to make subclass methods available without casting.

I’m not sure what your intended purpose of getSpecificType() is, but you could probably do away with that method and make things simpler:

```
public abstract class TestObject<T> {

    private T value;

    public abstract boolean test(T valueToTest);

    public static TestObject<Boolean> newInstance(boolean initialValue) {
        TestObject<Boolean> instance = new TestObjectBoolean();
        instance.setValue(initialValue);
        return instance;
    }

    public static TestObject<String> newInstance(String initialValue) {
        TestObject<String> instance = new TestObjectString();
        instance.setValue(initialValue);
        return instance;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T newValue) {
        this.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.

What I am trying to accomplish is passing a type to a method, and returning a subclass created with that type in mind.

TestObject exists with subclasses TestObjectString and TestObjectBoolean.

I think I would like to create methods with the same name that take in the respective classes:  

 `TestObjectString TestObject(String x) {
    return new TestObjectString
    }`  
   `TestObjectBoolean TestObject(Boolean x) {
    return new TestObjectBoolean}`
so that it can be used like this:   
  `new TestObject(Boolean.class).booleanSpecificMethod()`

Comment: You can do that with factory methods that return different subtypes, but there is no way the same class (TestObject) can have different methods under different circumstances.

Comment: I understand that TestObject's methods cannot change. I just want to hide the logic for creating different subclasses like TestObjectString and TestObjectBoolean depending on what type of parameter is used.


 How would i make different factory methods that are the same name?

This works for methods test(String a) and test(Boolean a) but when I add a test(T a) - where T is the generic type- i get the 'method is ambiguous' error. I would like to support generic cases and situations where it is a string or boolean. It looks like I cannot create methods for T which exclude certain types.

Comment: @testngthrowaway Updated answer.  Not sure if I’ve addressed your needs.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I implemented something similar as well, creating a factory method for the string, one for boolean, and one for T to support any other generic type.